# Unkown permission issues preventing wsl2 from accessing random windows files/directories

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having permissions issues when accessing seemingly random directories/files on the windows filesystem with wsl2/ubuntu. Some directories are not accessible and I get a 'permission denied' error when I try to access them or any of the files in them. However, I have no issues accessing them from Windows itself through explorer or a non-admin powershell or command-line shell.

From the WSL side I am the owner of the files and directories and have correct permissions but I still cannot access them. I can however access these directories/files if I switch to root. I shouldn't have to though since the permissions on this directory are the same as the ones on other directores.

drwxr-xr-x me me

I've tried looking at the directory properties from the Windows side and making them more permissive ("Full-control" to each group in the properties>security menu) to all of the various groups with no success. I am the only user of this computer and the only groups that exist are...

```
Authenticated Users
SYSTEM
Administrators (${my-machine-name}\Administrators)
Users (${my-machine-name}\Users)
```

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Are these always Windows files that you're accessing through WSL? I've also run into issues when the files are corrupted, not sure that's the issue here though.

Comment: They are windows files and directories. I can access them fine on the windows side, could they somehow only be corrupted through wsl? I can also access them fine if I switch to su.

Comment: Maybe not corrupted, but encoded differently, in a way that Linux doesn't agree with. Microsoft doesn't even recommend WSL2 for extensive Windows file access anyway. Maybe try switching to WSL to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be the issue, I switched to WSL 1 with ```wsl --set-default-version 1``` on an admin powershell and after restarting my computer and ubuntu shell I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Well, for starters, that command only changes the default version for *newly created* WSL instances.  To change an existing instance, you'd use `wsl --set-version <distro> 1`.  That said, I don't believe this is going to have any effect.  I'd also recommend a backup of the instance first with `wsl --export <distro> <filename.tar>` if do try it.

Comment: I've since switched back to wsl2 but I can confirm that I switched it to wsl1. I think I used the other command as well. I also can confirm that I ran the ```wsl --list --verbose``` command and it returned this after I restarted and started the ubuntu shell.
```  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         1```
That said my issue seems to have been resolved now, but I'm not sure as to how so I'm trying to put everything that I tried in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that not only the directory that contains the files has rx for your WSL user but also every directory above it (Sorry, would have commented but I don't have enough rep yet).

Comment: I noticed that the folder was having trouble accessing now showed ```drw-r-xr-x me me``` so running ```chmod u+x``` fixed it. I'm not sure If I was being dense and the folder didn't have execute permissions originally or if switching to wsl1 fixed the directory to reflect the actual permissions being enforced but that seemed to fix it.  I am currently running wsl1 because I didn't switch back yet so maybe wsl2 was actually the issue? Idk

Comment: Switched back to wsl2 with no permissions issues so I can confirm that switching bback doesn't seem to break it

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following:

```
[automount]
options="metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022"
```

After creating the file:

- Exit your WSL session
- `wsl --terminate <distro>` or `wsl --shutdown`
- Then restart and test the file/directory permissions again.

The `uid` and `gid` probably already default to those values since you mention that the files and directories on the NTFS drive are showing as owned by your user.  So they can probably be left out.

The `metadata` option is important, as it allows WSL to map Linux permissions on to files and directories created *in WSL* on those NTFS drivers.  But again, this isn't really your problem here either.

The `umask` is hopefully the long-term answer to your problem, as it will map WSL/Linux `rwxr-xr-x` to directories created *in Windows*, and `rw-r–r–` to files.

Comment: I think I tried something similar to this before I asked this question. I created a file at /etc/wsl.conf with 

```[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"```
  
Doing this didn't fix my problem (or I misread the file permissions initially as I stated in ). If I understand correctly though, this should prevent this problem from happening in the future?